# Modelling with a non-orthogonal image

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model a stormtrooper chest-plate with some non orthogonal reference images and I am struggling to figure out the best way of tackling it. Any tips for modelling this way would help a lot.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Answer (score 0):

Draw the main lines of the object:

[image]

Pull and pull the edges in order to create 3D, extrude some edges:

[image]

Comment: With the image looking at the trooper from an angle how would I align the mesh to it properly? to get an accurate side view.

Comment: You can only guess how it looks in side view, use as many pictures as you can